# flex combobox dropdown textAlign issue

Tags: apache-flex, combobox

I have a combobox where the `textAlign` defaults to `center`.  I tried setting it to `texAlign="left"`, but the text is still centered.

```
<s:HGroup width="100%" height="90%" textAlign="left">
        <s:VGroup width="45%" height="100%" textAlign="left">
            <s:Label width="100%" fontSize="12" text="Company Name:" textAlign="left"
                     verticalAlign="middle"/>
            <s:TextInput id="companyNameForm" width="100%"/>
            <s:Label width="100%" fontSize="12" text="Industry:" textAlign="left"/>
            <s:ComboBox id="companyIndustryForm" x="0" width="100%"
                        creationComplete="LoadIndustList(event)" labelField="IndustryEn"
                        selectedIndex="1"/>
            <s:Label  width="100%" fontSize="12" text="Contact Person:" textAlign="left"/>
            <s:TextInput id="companyContactPersonForm" width="100%"/>
            <s:Label  width="100%" fontSize="12" text="Contact Phone:" textAlign="left"/>
            <s:TextInput id="companyContactPhoneForm" width="100%"/>
            <s:Label width="100%" fontSize="12" text="Created By:" textAlign="left"/>
            <s:TextInput id="companyCreatedByForm" width="100%"/>
            <s:Label width="100%" fontSize="12" text="Created Date" textAlign="left"/>
            <s:TextInput id="companyCreatedDateForm" width="100%"/>

        </s:VGroup>
```

Comment: Is this the same code that you are using ? if it is your `ComboBox` element is missing the `textAlign` property please add it to the `ComboBox` and try again.

Comment: already done that still gives a centre align